# tic tac toe assignment in Python 3.3.5

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm almost done with an assignment to make a tic-tac-toe game, but for the life of me I can't work through an error I'm encountering in it upon execution. Any advice would be immensely appreciated.

Code link: http://pastebin.com/k7deVCAD

error upon execution:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/program2.1.py", line 168, in 
    I_hope_this_works ()

File "C:/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/program2.1.py", line 145, in I_hope_this_works
    play (player_names, player_marks)

File "C:/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/program2.1.py", line 154, in play
    askUserToPlayNextMove (player_names['X'], player_marks) #asks them to input move
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/program2.1.py", line 52, in askUserToPlayNextMove
    (row, column)= input("Please input your next move in row, column format ")

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
askUserToPlayNextMove (currentPlayer, player_marks)
```

needs two arguments, but you passed them as a single tuple:

```
askUserToPlayNextMove ((player_names['X'], player_marks))
```

try this:

```
askUserToPlayNextMove (player_names['X'], player_marks)
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved that Error! but now I found more...will update post

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is just that you have an extra set of parenthesis when calling the function "askUserToPlayNextMove."

You have the function call as:

```
askUserToPlayNextMove ((player_names['X'], player_marks))
```

and I think simply changing it to:

```
askUserToPlayNextMove (player_names['X'], player_marks)
```

will solve your problem. When you put the extra set of parenthesis around the arguments in the function call, it interprets the data inside of those parenthesis as corresponding to one of the parameters in the function. Removing the extra set will pass those arguments as two separate arguments instead of one.